# error: conflicting types for 'removeSpaces'

Tags: c, string, strdup

I want to write a program which will verify whether the string is palindrome or not.
But there is an error when I try to pass `strings[0]` to `removeSpaces` function which will remove spaces.

Why does '`comflicting types` error' occurs? What is wrong?

The whole code of programm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * removeSpaces(char *); // prototype

int main()
{
    char *strings[2]; // created array of pointers

    strings[0] = strdup("a man a plan a canal panama");
        printf("%s\n", strings[0]);

    strings[1] = removeSpaces(strings[0]);
        printf("%s\n", strings[0]); 
        /* (in future) it will display "amanaplanacanalpanama" */

    free(strings[0]);

    return 0;
}


char * removeSpaces(char * str[0]) // an ERROR occurs here 
{
    /* some code */

    return -1; // in case of fault
}
```

Comment: change `char * str[0]` to `char *str`

Comment: @pinkpanther, sting. I want to pass a sting.

Comment: Do you want to say that I pass a character instead of string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two issues:

1. Your function declaration and definition conflicted. You don't have to specify 
   `char *str[0]`, `char *str` is enough and it should match with your declaration at the top.
2. You are returning  `-1` instead of a pointer which is not a valid pointer in its form. If some fault occurs I would recommend you to return `NULL` instead.
3. `-1` is an integer. But however, you can also use `0` instead, because that defaults to `(void *)0` nothing but `NULL`.

change like this:

```
 char * removeSpaces(char * str) // an ERROR occurs here 
{
    /* some code */

    return NULL; // return NULL in case of fault instead of -1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a function, each parameter needs a type and a name.  Your `removeSpaces` function takes a single parameter of type `char *`, so you'd declare it as

```
char * removeSpaces(char * str)
```

Remember, the function doesn't know that you'll be passing it the first element of an array; it just knows you'll give it a pointer to a string of characters.

It's also the convention in C to return a null pointer when its data is missing or would be invalid.  So instead of returning -1 if there's an error, you should return `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration:

```
char * removeSpaces(char *);
```

Is different from the definition:

```
char * removeSpaces(char * str[0]);
```

Change the prototype:

```
char * removeSpaces(char *);
```